# How to use contour in math mode for italic symbols?

Tags: math-mode, bold, italic, contour

I'm trying to make bold symbols bolder in math mode (`\boldsymbol` isn't bold enough for my liking), and so far the best solution I've found is using `contour`. However, when contour is used within math mode, it makes the symbols lose their italic behavior. Is there a way to use contour within an equation to yield italic characters?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[outline]{contour}
\newcommand{\A}{\contour{black}{A}}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Using math mode within contour works:
\contour{black}{$A$} $ = 1$

\item but I want to use contour within math mode:
$\contour{black}{A} = 1$

\item since I'd like to eventually define the variables as bold elsewhere in the document:
$\A = 1$
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Here's why `\bm` isn't bold enough for me: Can you tell easily which r's are bolded?
[image]

vs using contour:
[image]

Comment: You could use `$\contour{black}{$A$} = 1$` but why not use the bold math font?

Comment: I really thought I had tried that solution! This worked for me, thanks! The bold math font isn't bold enough for my liking, since it's hard to differentiate for some characters.

Comment: but have pity on your readers, this is a fuzzy ugly **_A_** and really distracts the reading.

Comment: I agree it is distracting, so I may try to play with the contour length to find a sweet spot.

Comment: yes  can easily tell the bold r in your image: denominator r not bold;  numerator r and r not in fraction bold. The second is no clearer, just uglier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

You could use `$\contour{black}{$A$} = 1$` but this produces a rather fuzzy bold, and doesn't work in supercripts without adding further complication of `\mathchoice`. It is generally better to use a bold font.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[outline]{contour}
\newcommand{\A}{\contour{black}{$A$}}
\usepackage{bm}
\bmdefine\Abm{A}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Using math mode within contour works:
\contour{black}{$A$} $ = 1$

\item but I want to use contour within math mode:
$\contour{black}{$A$} = 1$

\item since I'd like to eventually define the variables as bold elsewhere in the document:
$\A = 1$
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}
\item Using math mode within contour works: $\bm{A} = 1$

\item but I want to use contour within math mode:
$\bm{A} = 1$

\item since I'd like to eventually define the variables as bold elsewhere in the document:
$\Abm = 1$
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the elaboration David! I added an edit to my original post to show why ```\bm``` isn't bold enough for me. Maybe it's a font thing?